# 1.Kindly see who is there" "She told me to see who was there/who there was" Should i put "was" before or after "there"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, passive-voice, british-english, active-vs-passive

1.Kindly see who is there"
"She told me to see who was there/who there was"
2.I just openend the door to check who was there or who there was".

Should I put "was" before or after "there"?

Comment: Your example context is unnecessarily confusing because it involves "backshifted" reported speech. Postulate a *Present Tense* version of essentially the same context. #1 - *Someone is ringing the doorbell. Please go and see **who is there***. #2 - (Telephonist speaking to caller wanting to talk to Mr Smith, who's not available) *Mr Smith isn't here, but I'm sure one of his colleagues can help you. Please wait a moment while I see **who there is***.

Comment: @fumblefingers with due respect do you not think that gotube has said otherwise in his/her remarks as gotube has put "there" in last. I am little confused.

Comment: With due respect, gotube's answer (which is perfectly accurate, so far as it goes) doesn't even *begin* to address the subtle usage point raised in my previous comment. In that highly specific "Mr Smith is not available" context, the phone operator quite naturally says *I'll see who there **is*** (not *...who **is there*** - if she was gonna say that, it would be *I'll see who **is** here*, not "there"). That's because the underlying sense of the utterance is something like *There may be someone else who can help. I'll see who [**there**] **is** here who can talk to you instead of Mr Smith*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"She told me to see who **was there**" is correct.

In that sentence, "there" indicates a place, so it means, "She told me to see who was *in that place*". Reversing it doesn't make sense: "*She told me to see who **in that place was**.*"

Comment: and how about this " I feel panicked at the thought of how few days "there are"/are there" before christmas"

Comment: That's "there are", as in, "***There are** so few days before Christmas*"

Comment: "I do not know how many milk bottles there are"/are there. I guess "are there" is correct as "there" is indicating a place as you mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: She told me to see who **was there**. ( 'There' is not the subject, 'who' is the subject. So 'there was' is incorrect and 'who was' is correct.)

[What *was he* doing?

She told me to see what **he was** doing. (NOT was he)

Who *are you*? I asked him who he was. (NOT who was he)

Who am I? She asks me who I am. (NOT who am I)

*There are* five bananas on the table. How many bananas *are there* on the table? I do not know how many bananas **there are**... Do you know how many bananas **there are**...? ]